# Не приходит ответ JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Не могу вывести ответ JSON'а. В браузере, во вкладке Network->Preview ответ есть,в JSON-формате, но вставить в html я его не могу.
Пробовал разные методы, ничего не получается.
В html все прописано и jquery добавлен.
Вот код:
**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from post WHERE id = (select max(id) from post where id < '$id')");
    $post = $sql->fetch_assoc();

    $data['postid'] = $post['id'];
    $data['image'] = $post['image'];

    echo json_encode($data);
}

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$post = $sql->fetch_assoc();

echo '
    <div class="content">
        <img src="'.$post['image'].'" class="next" data-id="'.$post['id'].'">
    </div>';
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.next').click(function(e) {
    var id = $('.next').data('id');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            //не работает
            $(".content").text(JSON.parse(data));
            //не работает
            $(".next").attr({"src":data.image, "data-id":data.postid});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: после вывода json не хотите скрипт случаем завершить? можете добавить туда вывода заголовка `content-type` и убрать лишний `JSON.parse` из js

Comment: У вас в аяксе адрес запроса не указан

Comment: @Plikard это не обязательный параметр. запрос отправляется на текущую страницу

Comment: Где `url` в `ajax` и зачем `JSON.parse`, если у вас в php `json_encode($data);` И перед выводом на страницу, выводите в консоль, так сразу увидите ошибку `console.log(JSON.parse(data));`

Comment: зы: избавьтесь от возможной sql инъекции. используйте параметры в запросах, а не подстановку значения в код. И запрос на выбрку предыдущего можете переписать без `max`, также как и в общем случае сделав `order by id desc limit 1` только в `where` добавить `id < :id`

Comment: @teran м-да, с **content-type** даже в браузер перестал ответ приходить. Лишний **JSON.parse** убрал. И ничего не изменилось. за **ЗЫ** спасибо

Comment: Что говорит `console.log`?

Comment: @Dmitriy Saxarov Молчит. Ничего нет. Даже alert не выскакивает, если его прописать. Проблема в success'е, как я понимаю.

Comment: `exit` то добавили,  или что?

Comment: Вы обрабатываете только success, добавте error , я думаю ответ у вас туда приходит

Comment: @teran добавил **return false;**

Comment: @PigHead мы ведь про пхп говорим, не про js?

Comment: @teran да, exit(); добавил php

Comment: Короче, вывел ошибки - **[object Object]**